# Outlook Express - Keep messages on server until deleted from inbox

Tags: email, pop3, outlook-express

Is it possible to keep email messages on the server only until they are deleted from the Outlook Express inbox? I know it is possible to download all of the messages from the server, but I want to keep them on the server and only delete them when they are deleted in Outlook Express.

Comment: Are you still using Outlook Express? Why? Also, POP3 or IMAP account?

Comment: Using POP, and Outlook Express because it's an old machine and its user doesn't like changes.

Comment: @user1049697 - POP3 doesn't support what you want.  You would have to use IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

.Hi User, please use IMAP.

** It offers two-way syncing between webmail and mail client actions. If you read a message in your email client, it will be marked read on the web!
** Save space by downloading only the message headers, or download whole messages to work offline.

** Your labels appear as folders, and vice versa, so it's easy to stay organized.

** Provides access to Drafts, Sent Mail and Spam folders.

** Great if you check your mail from multiple computers or mobile devices, you'll see the same messages and folders, no matter what email client you're using.

Here's a Link that you can check..

Gmail Support - http://mail.google.com/support/